# goBack не работает как надо

Tags: php, yii2

Я хотел сделать редирект на предыдущую страницу, но `$this->goBack()` в контроллере возвращает на главную. Гуглил, нашел такое решение `$this->goBack(Yii::$app->request->referrer)`. Оно какое-то время работало, а потом почему-то перестало и тоже теперь редиректит на главную все время. Неужели никак нельзя сделать редирект именно на предыдущую страницу? Я просто этот редирект очень много где понатыкал и не везде есть возможность сделать явный редирект на нужную страницу потому что попасть на эту могут с разных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать, `Yii::$app->request->referrer`, который возвращает последнюю страницу, на которой был пользователь.

Использование:

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

Вы должны учитывать, что referrer может быть null:

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
```

Смотрите [документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$referrer-detail)

Comment: Гениально. Взять и повторить то что я уже написал. А то что я написал что это не работает - даже дочитать поленился.

Comment: Что у вас в Yii::$app->request->referrer? Сделайте `var_dump();`

Comment: Там именно та ссылка со страницы с которой пришел запрос. Но тем не менее редиректит на главную что мне совсем не нужно.

Comment: Вы используете `goBack` или `redirect`?

Comment: goBack (тут еще 9 символов)

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `goBack` использовать `redirect`

Comment: Да, вот сейчас редирект заработало как надо, спасибо. Интересно почему же goBack такой кривой? :(

Comment: @Dark Byte, Получается, мой ответ был верный! И я не просто повторил то, что вы уже написали. А вы даже поленились прочитать мой ответ!

Comment: Мне кажется или вначале там было написано $this->goBack(Yii::$app->request->referrer) а потом вы поменяли ответ? Ну ок тогда.

Comment: Вы можете нажать на "изменен" и посмотреть, что было изменено

Comment: Тогда ок, сори. Я сам невнимательно прочитал ответ.